# Ajax request return success message but data does not insert into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending a ajax request it also returning success message but data is not inserting. Basically it is a link, when I will will click on the link then ajax will send a request to controllers and in database it increase the value with the previous value by 1. I have tried pass huge times but failed. This is a codignator project. It will grateful if you kindly help.

```js
Ajax File :

$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#like").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); // <------this will restrict the page refresh
        var post_id = $(this).prop('rel');
     $.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/ci_website/index.php/site/add_like",
         type: 'POST',
         data : post_id,
            dataType: 'json',
         success: function(res) {

             if (res.success) {
              alert(res.msg);
                } else {
                    alert(res.msg);
                }
         }

     });

     return false;
 }); 

});
```

```html
View File :

<a id="like" class="like_btn" rel="<?php echo $blog['blog_id'];?>" href="<?php echo site_url('site/add_like') . '/' . $blog['blog_id'];?>">Like</a>
```

Controller File :

```
 public function add_like()
{
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $post_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->db->set('post_like', '`post_like` + 1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('blog_id', $post_id);
        $add_post_view = $this->db->update('wb_blog');
        if ($add_post_view) {
            die(json_encode(array('success' => true, 'msg' => 'Your Like has been sent successfully.')));
        } else die(json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'Something bad happened!!! Please, try again.')));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 url: "http://localhost/ci_website/index.php/site/add_like/"+post_id,
```

I have add 'post_id' after the link. This is work fine. I did not define the exact id against which the row of the table will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

check with

```
if ($this->db->_error_message()) {
return FALSE; // Or do whatever you gotta do here to raise an error
} else {
return $this->db->affected_rows();
}`
```

Comment: I want to increase the value of 'post_like' row. It will count the like of a post.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the function, you're only loading the function, and since the loading of the file succeeded,  it returns true. 
After defining the function try calling it and see if that does work.